# How to place text next to image using gwtbootstarp3

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwtbootstrap3

I am using GWTBootstarp3 mentioned in the following link http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#images

with my gwt project. I am trying to move my heading text next to image but it is appearing in two lines.

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
    xmlns:b="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui">
    <b:Container fluid="true">
        <g:FlowPanel>
            <b:Image type="ROUNDED" url="images/logo.jpg" addStyleNames="topLeft"></b:Image>
            <b:Heading size="H1" text="My Application Title" addStyleNames="topLeft"></b:Heading>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </b:Container>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because a `Heading` has `display: block` which results in such behavior.
What you should do is probably wrap your `Image` in a `Heading`:

```
<b:Heading size="H1" addStyleNames="topLeft">
    <b:Image type="ROUNDED" url="images/logo.jpg" />
    <h:Text text="My Application Title" />
</b:Heading>
```